# Enabling and disabling activity or whole application in Android (AOSP source)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-source

First of all, I'm working inside AOSP environment and both of applications I mention here are built with Android source code and are system apps (UID is system).

App that is started on first boot/factory reset is written to utilize `android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD` intent filter. When app did it's job, it disables it's activity with code

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.xyzapp",
              "com.xyzapp.MainActivity"),
              PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
```

That all works fine. Problem I'm facing is re-enabling that activity which I'm trying to do from another application (Service to be more precise).

It is pretty much same as disabling it:

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.xyzapp",
              "com.xyzapp.MainActivity"),
              PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);
```

This approach is not working and I can't figure out why.

Here is quick overview how it should work:

- First boot - start `com.xyzapp.MainActivity` **before** launcher starts
- If OTA update is available and user decides to download and install it, at far end of process before going to recovery and installing update `com.xyzapp.MainActivity` should be re-enabled so it starts on next boot **before** launcher

Any tips, ideas?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

So checking `private void setEnabledSetting(final String packageName, String className, int newState, final int flags, int userId, String callingPackage)` from `PackagemanagerService.java` these are the key security checks it has:

1. Check if the `uid` of the calling process is `system` or not. If it's `system`, all is save, if not, it should have `android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE` permission.
2. Check if it's a protected package, which does not allow others to modify it's state.

For both this cases, you get a `SecurityException`, with different messages.

1. `throw new SecurityException(
                       "Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid="
                       + Binder.getCallingPid()
                       + ", uid=" + uid + ", package uid=" + pkgSetting.appId);`
2. `throw new SecurityException("Cannot disable a protected package: " + packageName);`

Do you get any of those SecurityExceptions? Try adding the permission: `CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE`.
What processes are you trying to enable the app from? What UID does it have? If you can make it be system, I'd say you will avoid some of the security checks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but that did not work unfortunately for me. However, I was missing CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE permission in manifest so that is one bug less I guess :). I will work on this more and will post if I figure out what is happening.

Comment: But do you have any errors in logcat? What is the UID for the service you are calling from?

Comment: I have to check that, did not had time to do it before. Will do that over weekend probably. Did not wanted to be rude and not reply anything for so long. I will post logcat details soon.

Comment: Since I did not had time to investigate further, I created service in term of bash script which is started when boot completes and installs packages from my folder using pm install command.